Join two data frames using the last row from each group
Our weather station recorded daily weather data (about 7 rows/observations) per week. We collected disease data once per week (one observation/row per week). How can I join the last row of the weather_df with disease_df while keeping other cells blank? I've tried using left_join, but it incorrectly adds one value from disease_df to all days of the week instead of recording the disease data at the end of the week.
Reproducible example
weather_df <- structure(list(week = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), levels = c("1", "2"), class = "factor"), 
    date = structure(c(1401062400, 1401148800, 1401235200, 1401321600, 
    1401408000, 1401494400, 1401580800, 1401667200, 1402272000, 
    1402358400, 1402444800, 1402531200, 1402617600, 1402704000, 
    1402790400, 1402876800), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    rainfall = c(0.8, 0, 1.4, 3, 0, 1, 0, 0, 3, 0, 2.4, 1.2, 
    0, 0, 0, 0), temperature = c(23.6, 21.9, 22.6, 20.1, 21.9, 
    20.3, 17.3, 15.5, 23.1, 22.4, 21.1, 20.4, 21.2, 21.5, 20.2, 
    20.4)), row.names = c(NA, -16L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))


disease_df <- structure(list(week = structure(1:2, levels = c("1", "2"), class = "factor"), 
    disease_intensity = c(0.4, 0.3)), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))



combine_df <- left_join(weather_df, disease_df, by = "week")

Here is the output

As you can see 0.4 is added to all days of week 1 and 0.3 is added to all days of week 2. I just want these to be added to the last days of both weeks,while keeping the other cells blank.

There are many join techniques you can use but in this case its easier to just enhance the join criteria. I added two criteria, the day of the week and cumulative count of that day as your week count includes two same days of week.
From there a regular left join works
library(tidyverse)

weather_augmented_tbl <- weather_df |> 
  group_by(week) |> 
  mutate(
    wday=wday(date)
    ,n_wday=cumsum(if_else(wday==2,1,0))
  )

disease_augmented_tbl <- disease_df |> 
  mutate(
    wday=2
    ,n_wday=2
  )

left_join(
  weather_augmented_tbl
  ,disease_augmented_tbl
  ,by=join_by(
    week,wday,n_wday
  )
)


Thanks. This works, but is there a way to automatically select the last row of the week? I have another data set in which weather data is recorded at hourly intervals, so there many rows for a single date. Disease was recorded at different times of the day, so hard to define a condition.

darren below provided an easier solution without needing to augment the tables.

You can merge disease_df and weather_df with "last-match", and join the result back to weather_df.
library(dplyr)

left_join(disease_df, weather_df, by = "week", multiple = "last") %>%
  left_join(weather_df, .)


Another option is to create a flag column in weather_df indicating the last day of each week, and then merge to disease_df.
weather_df %>%
  mutate(flag = row_number() == which.max(date), .by = week) %>%
  left_join(mutate(disease_df, flag = TRUE), by = join_by(week, flag)) %>%
  select(-flag)


Output
# # A tibble: 16 × 5
#    week  date                rainfall temperature disease_intensity
#    <fct> <dttm>                 <dbl>       <dbl>             <dbl>
#  1 1     2014-05-26 00:00:00      0.8        23.6              NA  
#  2 1     2014-05-27 00:00:00      0          21.9              NA  
#  3 1     2014-05-28 00:00:00      1.4        22.6              NA  
#  4 1     2014-05-29 00:00:00      3          20.1              NA  
#  5 1     2014-05-30 00:00:00      0          21.9              NA  
#  6 1     2014-05-31 00:00:00      1          20.3              NA  
#  7 1     2014-06-01 00:00:00      0          17.3              NA  
#  8 1     2014-06-02 00:00:00      0          15.5               0.4
#  9 2     2014-06-09 00:00:00      3          23.1              NA  
# 10 2     2014-06-10 00:00:00      0          22.4              NA  
# 11 2     2014-06-11 00:00:00      2.4        21.1              NA  
# 12 2     2014-06-12 00:00:00      1.2        20.4              NA  
# 13 2     2014-06-13 00:00:00      0          21.2              NA  
# 14 2     2014-06-14 00:00:00      0          21.5              NA  
# 15 2     2014-06-15 00:00:00      0          20.2              NA  
# 16 2     2014-06-16 00:00:00      0          20.4               0.3


nice! more efficient then mine

Darren's answer unfortunately didn't work for me. I got all NA with the flag option and got an error with the multiple option Error in left_join(): ! Join columns in xmust be present in the data. ✖ Problem withmultiple`.
Backtrace:

... %>% left_join(weather_dat_daily, .)
dplyr:::left_join.data.frame(...)`


@Ahsk I guess you're using an out-of-date dplyr version. You could install the latest one with install.packages("dplyr") and try again.

Just add max dates to disease_df and merge.
> merge(weather_df, 
+       transform(disease_df, 
+                 date=with(weather_df, tapply(date, week, max))),
+       all=TRUE)
   week       date rainfall temperature disease_intensity
1     1 2014-05-26      0.8        23.6                NA
2     1 2014-05-27      0.0        21.9                NA
3     1 2014-05-28      1.4        22.6                NA
4     1 2014-05-29      3.0        20.1                NA
5     1 2014-05-30      0.0        21.9                NA
6     1 2014-05-31      1.0        20.3                NA
7     1 2014-06-01      0.0        17.3                NA
8     1 2014-06-02      0.0        15.5               0.4
9     2 2014-06-09      3.0        23.1                NA
10    2 2014-06-10      0.0        22.4                NA
11    2 2014-06-11      2.4        21.1                NA
12    2 2014-06-12      1.2        20.4                NA
13    2 2014-06-13      0.0        21.2                NA
14    2 2014-06-14      0.0        21.5                NA
15    2 2014-06-15      0.0        20.2                NA
16    2 2014-06-16      0.0        20.4               0.3


In base R, we can merge twice
merge(weather_df, 
      merge(disease_df, aggregate(date ~ week, weather_df, max), by = "week"), 
      by= c("week", "date"), all.x = TRUE)

   week       date rainfall temperature disease_intensity
1     1 2014-05-26      0.8        23.6                NA
2     1 2014-05-27      0.0        21.9                NA
3     1 2014-05-28      1.4        22.6                NA
4     1 2014-05-29      3.0        20.1                NA
5     1 2014-05-30      0.0        21.9                NA
6     1 2014-05-31      1.0        20.3                NA
7     1 2014-06-01      0.0        17.3                NA
8     1 2014-06-02      0.0        15.5               0.4
9     2 2014-06-09      3.0        23.1                NA
10    2 2014-06-10      0.0        22.4                NA
11    2 2014-06-11      2.4        21.1                NA
12    2 2014-06-12      1.2        20.4                NA
13    2 2014-06-13      0.0        21.2                NA
14    2 2014-06-14      0.0        21.5                NA
15    2 2014-06-15      0.0        20.2                NA
16    2 2014-06-16      0.0        20.4               0.3

Pretty sure this can be written more concise.

A variation of @Darren Tsai's solution with right_join:
library(tidyverse)

new_df <- arrange(right_join(disease_df , weather_df, by = "week", multiple = "last"), date)

The output:
> new_df
# A tibble: 16 × 5
   week  disease_intensity date                rainfall temperature
   <fct>             <dbl> <dttm>                 <dbl>       <dbl>
 1 1                  NA   2014-05-26 00:00:00      0.8        23.6
 2 1                  NA   2014-05-27 00:00:00      0          21.9
 3 1                  NA   2014-05-28 00:00:00      1.4        22.6
 4 1                  NA   2014-05-29 00:00:00      3          20.1
 5 1                  NA   2014-05-30 00:00:00      0          21.9
 6 1                  NA   2014-05-31 00:00:00      1          20.3
 7 1                  NA   2014-06-01 00:00:00      0          17.3
 8 1                   0.4 2014-06-02 00:00:00      0          15.5
 9 2                  NA   2014-06-09 00:00:00      3          23.1
10 2                  NA   2014-06-10 00:00:00      0          22.4
11 2                  NA   2014-06-11 00:00:00      2.4        21.1
12 2                  NA   2014-06-12 00:00:00      1.2        20.4
13 2                  NA   2014-06-13 00:00:00      0          21.2
14 2                  NA   2014-06-14 00:00:00      0          21.5
15 2                  NA   2014-06-15 00:00:00      0          20.2
16 2                   0.3 2014-06-16 00:00:00      0          20.4

The right_join alone will do, but out of order (ie., in disease_df's order), hence the arrange. disease_intensity will be the second column (as in disease_df).
Edit
..and a one-liner base-r take:
# weather_df$new <- NA_real_ --> Avoid the "unknown or uninitialised colum" warning
weather_df$disease_intensity[cumsum(rle(as.numeric(weather_df$week))$lengths)] <- disease_df$disease_intensity

cumsum(rle(...)$lengths gives the position of last consecutive repeated element in a vector.
as.numeric(...) is necessary only because weather_df$week is a factor.
The same output:
> weather_df
# A tibble: 16 × 5
   week  date                rainfall temperature disease_intensity
   <fct> <dttm>                 <dbl>       <dbl>             <dbl>
 1 1     2014-05-26 00:00:00      0.8        23.6              NA  
 2 1     2014-05-27 00:00:00      0          21.9              NA  
 3 1     2014-05-28 00:00:00      1.4        22.6              NA  
 4 1     2014-05-29 00:00:00      3          20.1              NA  
 5 1     2014-05-30 00:00:00      0          21.9              NA  
 6 1     2014-05-31 00:00:00      1          20.3              NA  
 7 1     2014-06-01 00:00:00      0          17.3              NA  
 8 1     2014-06-02 00:00:00      0          15.5               0.4
 9 2     2014-06-09 00:00:00      3          23.1              NA  
10 2     2014-06-10 00:00:00      0          22.4              NA  
11 2     2014-06-11 00:00:00      2.4        21.1              NA  
12 2     2014-06-12 00:00:00      1.2        20.4              NA  
13 2     2014-06-13 00:00:00      0          21.2              NA  
14 2     2014-06-14 00:00:00      0          21.5              NA  
15 2     2014-06-15 00:00:00      0          20.2              NA  
16 2     2014-06-16 00:00:00      0          20.4               0.3

